# Angular Slider - 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, angular

I create an input slider.  When I slide along the bar, it will show a value number.  My code works well with javaScript: [sample in jsfidder](https://jsfiddle.net/a4skLj9e/)

But when I bring to Angular, it doesn't work!  Please take a look at [my sample here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qzpbe9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please help.  Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="range-wrap">
        <input id="range" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" (change)="onChangeDevidesRange()">
        <div class="devices-range-value" id="devices-range"></div>
    </div>
```

.ts

```
onChangeDevidesRange() {
  const
    range = document.getElementById('range[value]'),
    devicesRange = document.getElementById('devices-range'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        devicesRange.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        devicesRange.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

document.getElementById("range").oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, ' + this.value + '%, #fff ' + this.value + '%, white 100%)'
     }

CSS

```
.range-wrap{
    /* width: 500px; */
    position: relative;
}
#range {
  width: 100%;
}
.devices-range-value{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
.devices-range-value span{
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

}
```

Comment: First of all if you are still using document.getElement you can stay in Javasript jQuery world. If you are in angular world you should be doing this with ViewChild. For a quick hack if you want to write javascript in Angular world then `document.getElementById('range[value]') as any`

Answer (score 0):

Try this use elementRef in Angualr for Dom things :

```
    import { Component, VERSION , ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){

  }
 onChangeDevidesRange() {
  const
    range = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#range'),
    devicesRange = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#devices-range'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        devicesRange.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        devicesRange.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
this.elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue); 
 }
}
```